# No Microsoft graph notification after user mobile phone is changed

Tags: graph, notifications, microsoft-graph-api

We are testing Microsoft graph notification when you subscribed to user notifications.

In the azure user's admin console, there are few sections for the user like Identity, Contacts and other.

If we change some of the fields from Identity section like FirstName, LastName we get a notification.

If we change some fields from Contacts we don't get a notification.
My question is: Is this is correct behaviour? Or are there some "hidden" setting to get notification from the Contact section.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRLIe.png)

Answer (score 0):

The contact information that you highlight in the example is part of the user resource object.

You should see the phone number change in the user object by accessing it. You can test this in Graph Explorer here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com

Details on what properties are in the user resource object are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for your answer, but according to documentation I see, that we should get notification, but we don't and I don't understand why ?!?

Comment: @YuryLipovtsev, are you subscribing with value of `Resource: /users`?

I can confirm that any changes to `mobilePhone` or `streetAddress` property that are made on users do trigger a notification to go out.